# How to reference DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText manually in resources files?

Tags: c#, winforms

For transaction purposes, I created resources files which replace text property of my winforms components.

However, it seems i can't correctly reference my DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText property manually in the resources file; but I can change the HeaderText property of it in the code, but not in the resource file (it works for other components...)

I've also tried :

```
DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText = "test1";
DataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Value = "test2";
DataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "test3";
```

The code works when calling it but not when I put it in the resources file.

Comment: Are you saying that you wrote some C# code in a *.resx file? I knew that we simply place strings, images, icons and other such resources in resx file.

Comment: You can with code set `HeaderText` to text from resource file. `DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText = YourApplicationNamespace.Properties.Resources.DataGridViewHeaders.Column1` - where `DataGridViewHeaders` is name of resource file and `Column1` is key of your text

Comment: I put localize = true on my form, to be abble to traduce my labels in others languages and i manually update for each language each text label (string type in which i put for example button1.text on the left column; and the value traduced in the second column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using satellite assemblies for keeping localized text then you can do something like this :

```
//namespacaes to be imported at the top of your code file
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection; 

//source code for your method
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("TestSatelliteAssembly.Resources.LocalizedResources",Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText = resourceManager.GetString("lblUserNameText");
```

`lblUserNameText` is the key for the text you are trying to localize. `TestSatelliteAssembly` is the name of your satellite assembly.

You can read more about satellite assemblies in my blog [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801343/All-you-wanted-to-know-about-Satellite-Assemblies).

Comment: You can get rid of hardcoded keys - Visual Studio will generate properties for them - and provide you nice maintainable intellisense help